# Drupal Custom Module Hook_menu not working with querystring params

Tags: drupal-7, query-string, hook-menu

I am sending a link out via email to users when they register that they must click and it will automatically direct and log them into the site.

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to access this link.

Example email sent out:

www.someurl.com/custom_confirm/verify?email=test@test.com&hash=somehash

My hook menu in custom_confirm looks like this:

```
function custom_confirm_menu(){
    $items = array();

    $items['custom_confirm/verify'] = array(
        'title' => 'Confirming Registration',
        'page callback' => 'verify_email',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    ); 
    return $items;
}
```

My function

```
function verify_email()
```

Is not being invoked when I hit this URL. It's giving me a 404 and not hitting any code inside the verify_email function.

Is there something wrong with this hook_menu? I don't understand why this is not working?

Comment: It seems your syntax is allright, try 2 things, clear the cache and if it does not work disable then uninstall your custom module and reinstall it. Menus tend to be a pain to deal with when dynamically changing them on activated modules.
Also if your menu is just a callback then add type =>  MENU_CALLBACK, else it will be default value : MENU_NORMAL_ITEM wich is displayed in menus.

Comment: I realized it was because when I was pushing up to the DEV environment it was migrating the DB changes and not clearing cache on dev -.- was literally just a cache issue -.-